# mysql does not start or work

Tags: mysql, webserver, lamp, tasksel

Recently I installed LAMP with tasksel.
Then I remember I issued some commands to get into the mysql console - it worked. 
Right now I checked - apache and php modules work perfectly.
But as for mysql - whatever commands I issue - it does not start the console. It writes:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

How can I fix it and start mysql?
Why did this happen?
Where is it installed (I used the default location for the installation), because I dont understand what is started when I issue the commands?

Answer (score 1):

After Googling, your issue is commonly associated with either a bad hostname, or a misplaced socket file. [This Article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/) addresses the latter and proposes a solution.

---

Excerpt:

> To make your life easier, you can make a simple change to the MySQL
>   configuration file /etc/my.cnf that will permanently set the socket
>   file used by the mysql client. After making a backup copy of
>   /etc/my.cnf, open it in your favorite editor. The file is divided into
>   sections such as

```
[mysqld] datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysql.server] user=mysql basedir=/usr/local/mysql
```

> If there is not currently a section called [client], add one at the bottom of the file and copy the socket= line under the [mysqld]
>   section such as:
>
> ```
> [client] socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> ```
>
> If there is already a [client] section in the my.cnf file, add or edit
>   the socket line as appropriate. You won’t need to restart your server
>   or any other processes. Subsequent uses of the mysql client will use
>   the proper socket file.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Thanks, I was putting it in as you were commenting!

Comment: the file mysql.sock does not exist anywhere. what shall I do?